# Is it valid to turn $i^n$ into $((−1)^n)^{1/2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

For example, what is the value of $i^{83}~$? To my understanding, I can solve this problem in 2 different ways that give me different answers:

Solution 1:
$$
i^{83} = i^{82}i=(i^2)^{41}i=(-1)^{41}i=-i
$$

Solution 2:
$$
i^{83} = ((-1)^{1/2})^{83}=((-1)^{83})^{1/2}=(-1)^{1/2}=i
$$

Both solutions seem to be correct to me but they yield different results. Could someone please help me understand which one of these solutions is wrong and why?

Comment: For $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, $i^n=-i$. In particular, $i^{83}=-i$ since $83 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Comment: The index law you used in the second method is not valid when using the principal value of the square root (i.e. that $\sqrt{-1} = i$ and not $-i$)

Comment: I think this is quite a good question, but I think you should generalize it a bit more to get it more attention. As it is now, the title seems to be asking for the solution to a homework question, whereas the real question is one about applying specific exponent laws to $i$, which is a far more general and on-topic question. Your generalized title could be something of the ilk "Is it valid to turn $i^n$ into $((-1)^n)^{1/2}$?" And then you could keep the body of your question as an example of that question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @user110391 . I updated the title per your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @messenger. I think your answer is helpful, it would help me a lot if you could please elaborate with some details on why it is not valid to use the principal value of the square root. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution.1 is correct.

$i=i,~i^2=-1,~i^3=-i,~i^4=1$

$$i^{83}=i^3\cdot i^{80}=i^3=-i$$

Your solution.2 is wrong, because you need to specify the branch. If you take $-1=e^{i\pi}$, then $\sqrt{-1}=e^{i\pi /2}=i$
$$(i)^{83}=(-1)^{83/2}=((-1)^{83})^{1/2}=((e^{i\pi})^{83})^{1/2}=(e^{i\pi3})^{1/2}=e^{i\pi3/2}=-i$$

Comment: I think a good question to this ought to resolve the contradiction as well, instead of just asserting that one or the other is correct. Why was their second solution incorrect?

Comment: You need to specify the branch @user110391

Comment: Thank you @MathFail. I can understand the substitution with Euler's formula and how you got $-i$ as the result. Could you please elaborate on what "you need to specify the branch" means in this context? Thank you!

Comment: @strxwberri We need to specify a certain branch so that we don't have a function taking a single input to multiple outputs. We represent complex numbers as $z = re^{i(\theta + 2n\pi)}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. For instance, $-1$ can also equal $e^{i3\pi}$ (so $n = 1$ in this case), which would imply $\sqrt{-1} = e^{i3\pi/2} = \left(e^{i\pi/2}\right)^3 = i^3 = -i$. In fact, you can do this with any integer $n$ and see that you'd either get $i$ or $-i$ as a solution.